# I'm looking for idiom(s) which depicts 'someone is desperately searching for something good out of obvious disaster'

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Something like, someone is trying hard to justify something evil.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One idiom is about a silver lining in a cloud. Such as:
"Every Cloud has a Silver Lining."
or
"I'm just looking for the Silver Lining."

**EDIT**
Based on OPs comment: "Can I use this in a criticizing way?"
You can use it for criticism, but it has a different form, which varies based upon emotional state. Such as:
Polite: "You are looking for a silver lining where there isn't one?"
Angry: "You're wasting your/everyone's time searching for an imaginary silver lining. (sigh)"
Vulgar: "You're searching for a silver lining inside a turd!"

Comment: Thanks, can I use this as to criticising way, as in "you are searching for  the Sliver Lining in the earthquake that ruined the city"?

Comment: Edited my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think [“grasping at straws”](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grasping-at-straws) could work well here, it means

> trying to find some way to succeed when nothing you choose is likely to work

and

> trying to find a reason to feel hopeful in a bad situation:

While neither of these quite captures “desperately” from you question, it depends on where you get the explanation from as [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/grasp--at--straws) does actually use desperate in theirs:

> Make a desperate attempt at saving oneself